# what is the max value of an offset in setbit

Tags: redis

I have tried to store bit using `setbit` in redis like 
`setbit mykey 123 1` and also use more than maximal int value `2147483647 + 100` as the offset value so it would be like this :

`setbit mykey 2147483747 1` this one works. 
And also I tried to add severals number until hit the `4547483747` and got

> ERR bit offset is not an integer or out of range

my question is : what is the maximal exact value of the offset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://redis.io/commands/setbit):

> The *offset* argument is required to be greater than or equal to 0, and smaller than 2³²

So the maximum value is 4,294,967,295 (or 2³² - 1). Confirmation via the CLI:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> setbit mykey 4294967295 1
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> setbit mykey 4294967296 1
(error) ERR bit offset is not an integer or out of range
```